# Perl Crypt::CBC error handling

Tags: perl, encryption

I'm using Perl CBC to encrypt and decrypt messages, but the messages I get might sometimes be malformed. Right now, if I run decrypt on a malformed message, I get the error and the program dies:

`Ciphertext does not begin with a valid header for 'salt' header mode at /tmp/test.pl line 26.`

What is the correct/best way to deal with this? I can put it in an eval block and check for an error, e.g.,:

```
eval {
    my $decrypted = $cipher->decrypt_hex($malformed_message);
}

if ($@) {
    print "Well, that didn't work!\n";
}
```

but I'm wondering if there's a better way? It doesn't seem nice that Crypt::CBC just dies completely if it doesn't get nice input, rather than providing an error code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your crypto code so this cannot happen. If you don't, no matter how you handle the error, an attacker can induce errors in your system and using them can decrypt your messages. This is known as a [padding oracle attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_oracle_attack) and its rather devastating.

You need to authenicate your entire ciphertext with a message authentication code (e.g. HMACSHA256) or use an authenticated cipher text mode such as AES GCM so you can detect corruption before you try to decrypt it.

Sorry, I don't know Perl, but you'd want something like this for the MAC

```
if(verifyMAC(ciphertext,message):
    //decrypt and handle 
else:
   print "While that didn't work
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip Michael - if anyone else can point me to how to do this in Perl, I would appreciate it.

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/dist/Digest-HMAC/ Note, you need to compute the mac when you encrypt too. So it changes both the encryption and decryption code

Comment: If you have access to [GCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode) or some other authenticated encryption method, consider using that, as it's likely to be faster and easier than doing encryption and authentication manually.

Comment: Yep, this is in fact the better idea